# InputStream is null when trying to read a properties file in WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

My `InputStream` object is making the console print out a NullPointerException whenever I try to read a properties file that is located in "/WEB-INF". But when I do `InputStream.toString()` it prints out `java.io.FileInputStream@1933968` instead of an actual `null` value.

Here is the stack trace that I'm getting back:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/translator] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.webclaims.translator.TranslatorApi.readPropertiesFile(TranslatorApi.java:149)
at com.webclaims.translator.TranslatorApi.writePropertiesFile(TranslatorApi.java:128)
at com.webclaims.translator.controllers.TestController.editableWebpage(TestController.java:45)
```

The layout of `/WEB-INF`;

```
WEB-INF-|
        |-jsp
        |-configDummy.properties
        |-spring-servlet.xml
        |-web.xml
```

I'm running this project on a Tomcat v8 server with Java 8.

spring-servlet.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd  
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.webclaims.*" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="propertiesFile" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" value="/WEB-INF/configDummy.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>translator</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value> 
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener> 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

TestController.java(cotains the exceptions entry point)

```
@Controller
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/configDummy.properties")
public class TestController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class.getName());

private static final String PROPS_FILE = "/WEB-INF/configDummy.properties";

@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ModelAndView originalWebpage() {
    return new ModelAndView("testpage");
}

@CrossOrigin()
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String editableWebpage(@RequestBody String data, HttpServletRequest request) {
    InputStream inputStream = request.getSession().getServletContext()
            .getResourceAsStream(PROPS_FILE);
    System.out.println(inputStream);

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(data);
    Elements elements = parser.jsonToElements();
    TranslatorApi t = new TranslatorApi();
    t.writePropertiesFile(elements, inputStream);
    return data;
}
}
```

TranslatorApi.java

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/configDummy.properties")
public class TranslatorApi {

@Autowired
private Properties properties;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TranslatorApi.class.getName());

public TranslatorApi() {}

public Properties getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

public void writePropertiesFile(Elements elements, InputStream inputStream) {
    System.out.println("write opertion executed");
    System.out.println(elements);
    try {
        readPropertiesFile(inputStream);

        for(Element e : elements) {
            properties.setProperty(e.className(), e.text());
        }

        String path=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/props/configDummy.properties").toString();
        File file = new File(path);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        properties.store(fileOut, "DUMMY");
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readPropertiesFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    try {
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "FileNotFoundException has occured", e);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException has occured", e);     
    } 
}
```

Most people on here recommend that I should put the properties file in the classpath. If I have it in there will I be able to write to it in the future?

Comment: I could not see the line number. Just saw 2 line in the method readPropertiesFile which actually throw the NullPointerException.  properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close(); It could be the properties is NULL, not the InputStream. The properties might not be autowired and was NULL

Answer (score 1):

For me your NPE is more related to the fact that the field `properties` in `TranslatorApi` is `null` as it has not been properly injected.

Try to use the class `Environment` as next instead:

```
@Autowired
private Environment properties;
```

Here is a good example of [how to inject properties in your class](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/).

Comment: Do I have to use `Environment` class? I really want to use the `Properties` class because I want to make use of its `setProperty(key, value)` method.

Comment: Have you tested first with Environment to see if it is properly injected?